# Laravel query join gives Trying to get property of non-object

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

My Child Class

class Child extends Eloquent {
... 
    public function campaign() {
        return $this->hasOne('Campaign');
    }
...
}

Here is my query in Laravel:

```
    $query = Child::query();
    $query->select('children.*');
    $query->join('demands', 'demands.children_id', '=', 'children.id')->where('demands.accepted', '=', '1');
    $children = $query->orderBy(DB::raw('RAND()'))->take(4)->get();
```

In in foreach ($children as $child), I try to call echo  $child->campaign->name and I got "Trying to get property of non-object" message. $child->name works fine!

Comment: Is it possible that you have children in your db, that do not have a campaign?

Comment: Please accept my answer so everybody browsing the question list can see that this issue is resolved. thanks.

Comment: Have you check $children variable is a Array or Object ?
If it is Array than use $array->$key;
If it is Object than usr $object->$key;

Comment: Try echo @$child->campaign->name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So as it turned out, not every children had a campaign associated with it.
Just add a little check in your foreach loop and you should be fine

```
foreach($children as $child){
    if($child->campaign == null){
        continue;
    }
    // do stuff
}
```